# The requested address is not valid in its context UDP packet capture program

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am trying to capture udp data from the modem by C#. But when I run the code the following exception occurs:

> The requested address is not valid in its context    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.setMulticastOption(SocketOptionName
> optionName, MulticastOption MR)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel
> optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, Object optionValue)    at
> CAA..ctor() in C:\Users\Muhammed
> Kara\source\repos\UDPprogram\UDPprogram\CAA.cs:line 25 here are
> Wireshark properties: source IP: 192.168.1.150 dest IP: 192.168.1.140
> source port: 32768 dest port: 50000

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class CAA
{
    private Socket UDPSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    private IPAddress Target_IP;
    private int Target_Port;
    public static int bPause;

    public CAA()
    {
        Target_IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.140");
        Target_Port = 9999;

        try
        {
            IPEndPoint LocalHostIPEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
            UDPSocket.Bind(LocalHostIPEnd);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 0);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(Target_IP));
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Recieve");
            Recieve();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void Recieve()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
            EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = UDPSocket;
            Console.WriteLine("Begin Recieve");
            UDPSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, ref LocalEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new
        IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
        EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref LocalEndPoint);



        client.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, ref LocalEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }


    public class StateObject
    {
        public int BufferSize = 512;
        public Socket workSocket;
        public byte[] buffer;

        public StateObject()
        {
            buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        }
    }

}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UDPprogram
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CAA udpport = new CAA();
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `192.168.1.140` is not a multicast address so you can't join it

Comment: yeah I changed it, but I have a new problem I can not assign a multicast IP address to ethernet (ipv4)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact issue

Comment: I am trying to capture data coming from ethernet. In order to do this, I am listening to the IP address of the ethernet (192.168.1.140). Since this is not a multicast address I have to change this address with a multicast address. But when I try the change ethernet IP address on ethernet settings, it can not be changed. The error message is "'t save ip settings check one or more settings and try again"

Comment: Well an interface can't have a multicast address, that makes no sense. Are you trying to join a multicast group? Otherwise I don't see how it's relevant, you should just create a listener on a particular UDP port. I suggest you read up on how multicast actually works if you are trying to use it, you seem to have a misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, I got what you mean. What I am trying to do is to capture data from the ethernet port by c#. source IP: 192.168.1.150 dest IP: 192.168.1.140 source port: 32768 dest port: 50000. I will try a new code. If you know about this can you help?